# Geeting issue with installing php5-dev libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php

Tags: 16.04, php

I am using AWS vps first time, so didn't know enough about using server

using `PHP Version 7.0.28-0  ubuntu0.16.04.1`

getting issue with wordpress to uploading files from dashboard after searching from net I meet this solution

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

all steps done but stuck at `sudo apt-get install php5-dev libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php` when I enter this command I got following message in command line

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libssh2-php is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  php-ssh2

E: Package 'php5-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libssh2-php' has no installation candidate
```

please let me know solution or alternate package for this

thanks in advance

Comment: Try installing `php7.0-dev` instead of `php5-dev`.

Answer (score 2):

The DigitalOcean guide you're following is **deprecated** and not updated for the proper versions of Ubuntu nowadays.  It says this in their guide at the top.  It was written for Ubuntu 12.04

However, in 16.04, PHP5 does not exist, as it uses PHP7 now.  Also, `libssh2-php` is renamed to `php-ssh2`.

Install `php-dev` (which installs the PHP 7 dev libraries) and `php-ssh2`:

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev php-ssh2
```

This should install the 16.04-equivalent packages that you're looking for.